# Map object keeps getting overwritten when adding

Tags: java, jdbc, hashmap, resultset

I have a database call that will return a result set with city and states into a result set object called cityAndState. I am trying to loop through and put each city and state into a map and then add to an array list of maps.
So I have an array list with 50 city and state Maps with <key,values> of city and state.  For instance [{city-Los Angeles, state=California},...] But each time I am overwriting the value.

```
Map<String,String> citiesAndStateCombinations = new HashMap<>();

List<Map<String,String> citiesStates = new ArrayList<>();

while(cityAndState.next()){
citiesStates.put("city", cityAndState.getString("city");
citiesStates.put("state", cityAndState.getString("state");
citiesAndStateCombinations.add(citiesStates); 
}
```

Leaves an array with the last values printed 50 times.
[{city-Boise, state=Idaho}, {city=Boise, state=Idaho}.....50}

Each time it erases the previous value.  I see why it is doing it, it's setting all the elements to the last value added which makes sense but is there a way to add the values so I am left with an array of the 50 cities and States?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is you're implementing HashMap in the wrong way, or you misunderstood it: "A Map cannot contain duplicate keys and each key can map to at most one value."
What you're doing in the above code -

```
citiesStates.put("city", cityAndState.getString("city");
citiesStates.put("state", cityAndState.getString("state");
```

You're putting values with the same key "city" & "state" that's why it's overwriting the values.

The correct way to do this will be -

```
Map<String,String> citiesAndStateCombinations = new HashMap<>();

while(cityAndState.next()){
if(!citiesAndStateCombinations.containskey(cityAndState.getString("city"))){
   citiesAndStateCombinations.put(cityAndState.getString("city"), cityAndState.getString("state"))
}
}
```

This will give you a city and state unique map now if you want it to be added to a list you can add this line at last but I don't see any use of it -

```
List<Map<String,String> citiesStates = new ArrayList<>();
citiesStates.add(citiesAndStateCombinations);
```

Please add this after closing the while loop.

**----------EDITED----------**

To achieve the solution which you're looking for you need to write something like this -

```
enter code here
while(----){
Map<String,String> citiesAndStateCombinations = new HashMap<>();
if(citiesAndStateCombinations.containsKey("city="+cityAndState.getString("city"))){
    citiesAndStateCombinations.put(cityAndState.getString("city"), cityAndState.getString("state"))
    citiesStates.add(citiesAndStateCombinations);
}
```

This will give you desired output -

```
[{city=XXXXXX=state=XXXXXX}, 
{city=XXXXXX=state=XXXXXX}, 
{city=XXXXXX=state=XXXXXX}]
```

Comment: but this won't have {city=Boise, state=Idaho} this would have {Boise=Idaho}. I am having the problem you spoke about with each key being overwritten.  I need to have the string city as the key for each individual map.  {city=Boise, state=Idaho} then I would add that to list<Map<String,String>.  Next {city=austin, state=Texas} etc then add that to the list so I end up with {city=value, state=value}, ...{city=value, state=value}. I don't get why it is overwriting my list. I get it should overwrite the map but I add that map to the list.  so I shoudl be adding a new map each time right?

Comment: Okay so first to achieve this - {city=Boise, state=Idaho} change the PUT statement to map.put("city="+key, "state="+value) and for adding it to a list instead of adding a new map each time, what you can do is remove elements from the map by using the map.remove("city="+key) so at every iteration, your map will be empty initially

Comment: I hope this helps if yes please upvote and mark answered 

Comment: I thought I was wrapping {the key value pair} as individual objects and adding them into an List<Map<String,String>

Comment: I see I am not doing that, everytime i change it in the loop I am overwritting it globally.  there does not seem like a way to achieve a display like [{city=minneapolis, state=Minnesota}, {city=Boise, state=idaho}, {city=houston, state=texas}...50] I think I see what you are doing in your example but it looks like you are using the List at the end before it's even declared?  !citiesStates.containskey(cityAndState.getString("city")) is being called on a list not a map, is that what you meant?

Comment: Please check the solution after the EDITED